# text of input field is not showing the text while print on IOS

Tags: html, css, ios, input

I have a form with text input , write the text in and then we have a list with auto suggestions ,
It's working fine on all devices except IOS devices is not showing the text is not appear as in the below screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

This is the code that I used:

```
<div class="search">
<form action="@searchUrl" method="get">
    <div class="input-wrap" id="top_search">
        <input placeholder="@search" type="text" data-url="@autocompleteUrl" name="query" class="input-text" id="SearchInput" value="@searchKey" autocomplete="off">
        <button class="n-style" type="submit">
            <i class="icon-search"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

So how I can solve this problem please?

Comment: I have the same issue. Could'n find the reason why yet!! I'll answer here with my findings

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. Don't know if it was the same as Rawan's.
In my case I was controlling the visibility of the shadow pseudoelements that seem to work a bit different in iOS than in the rest of browsers. So, if you want to remove the default arrow do not hide it using ::-webkit-textfield-decoration-container but ::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator for Android and desktop browsers, and ::-webkit-list-button for iOS.

You can also customize the background image with these pseudo-classes